# Difference between == and .Equals() with Interfaces and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I recently got a "The mapping of interface member ..... is not supported" error, which I resolved based on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/bc2fbbce-eb63-4735-9b2d-26b4ab8fe589/).  To demonstrate:

```
public interface IMyInterface { string valueText { get; set; } }
public class MyData : IMyInterface
{
   int ID { get; set;}
   string valueText { get; set;}
}
public class MyOtherData : IMyInterface
{
   long ID { get; set;}
   string valueText { get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetByValue<T>(string value) : where T : class, IMyInterface, new()
{ 
   using (var context = new DataContext())
   { 
      // The important line
      return context.GetTable<T>().Where(x => x.valueText == value);
   }
}
```

Running this code, I'd get a NotSupportedException: "The mapping of interface member IMyInterface.valueText is not supported".  However, if I replace the `x.valueText == value` with `x.valueText.Equals(value)`, this works entirely as expected.

I've solved this in my code, but I want to understand *why* it behaves this way.  Can anyone explain it?

**Update:** As per my comment below, the LINQ to SQL team closed this as a "Won't fix".  I think that means it now counts as a known bug, but one that isn't going to be resolved any time soon.  I'd still like to know why it behaves differently in the first place, though.

Comment: After reading the thread you linked to, I would say that this looks like a bug.

Comment: @phoog, I'd assume a bug too, except there's an explicit error for it.    Which means that something has to be checking for that scenario.  It could be a "forgot to add the logic" type of bug, or an exception coded in to avoid a bug, but in and of itself, I think the exception is the "correct" behavior.

Comment: @ Bobson, did you check connect to see if anyone ever reported the bug?  A couple of people in the linked thread talked about it, but it seems like nobody had enough initiative to do it himself.

Comment: @phoog, No one's reported it as far as I could tell.  I just submitted it.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/737117

Comment: @phoog: Ok, I heard back.  "Thank you for the feedback on LINQ to SQL. We have reviewed the issue, but at this time have decided not to take the change to LINQ to SQL for the next release of the .NET Framework." and they marked it as a "Won't Fix".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the decision to push the query upstream to the server is made based on an incomplete set of rules, and then LINQ-to-SQL finds a construct (an interface) that it can't deal with.

The method call isn't supported by LINQ-to-SQL, so it generates a query to retrieve all records and then uses LINQ-to-Objects to filter them.  (Actually, based on your other thread, LINQ-to-SQL may make a special exception for `object.Equals` and knows how to convert that to SQL).

LINQ-to-SQL probably should fall back to the LINQ-to-Objects behavior when an interface is involved, but apparently it just throws an exception instead.

Comment: Oh I much prefer the exception.  Finding out that it was downloading the contents of the table to filter in memory would probably make me give up programming and join the circus.

Comment: If the accepted answer on the linked thread is to be believed, your conjecture is incorrect.  It appears that Linq to SQL generates identical correct SQL (including a `WHERE` clause for the filter) for both the `==` comparison and the `.Equals` call, but throws an exception nonetheless for the `==` comparison.

Comment: @Ben, But why does it behave differently between `==` and `.Equals()`?  As far as I know, they're the same thing behind the scenes, and as @phoog points out, they generate the same SQL.